# Conditionally summing/subtracting quantities

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have two tables (`PS_BU_ITEMS_INV A` and `PS_TRANSACTION_INV B`) that are used for inventory item management. `PS_BU_ITEMS_INV A` contains a field with the current on-hand quantity of am item `A.QTY_ONHAND`. The table `PS_TRANSACTION_INV B` is a transaction table that lists all the transactions (shipments, depletions, etc..) that either reduce or increase the `A.QTY_ONHAND` value in the `PS_BU_ITEMS_INV A` table from a field called `B.QTY_BASE`.

Values stored in the `B.QTY_BASE` column are all positives, so I have to look at another column called `B.TRANSACTION_GROUP` to determine if the quantity in `B.QTY_BASE` should be added or subtracted from the current `A.QTY_ONHAND` value.

Below is sample data from each of these tables

**PS_BU_ITEMS_INV:**

```
  SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, INV_ITEM_ID, QTY_ONHAND, DT_TIMESTAMP 
  FROM PS_BU_ITEMS_INV
  WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = '1'
  AND BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'
```

**Results:**

```
 BUSINESS_UNIT   INV_ITEM_ID    QTY_ONHAND    DT_TIMESTAMP
 11MMS           1              16.0000       2018-09-11 08:12:46.827
```

**PS_TRANSATION_INV:**

```
 SELECT  BUSINESS_UNIT, INV_ITEM_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE, 
  TRANSACTION_GROUP, QTY_BASE, DT_TIMESTAMP
 FROM PS_TRANSACTION_INV
 WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = '1'
  AND BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'
 ORDER BY DT_TIMESTAMP DESC
```

**Results:**

[image]

Suppose I want to determine what the `QTY_ONHAND` value was on September 4th; I would take the current `QTY_ONHAND` value from `PS_BU_ITEMS_INV` table (in this case it is 16.0 and add (sum) (from `PS_TRANSACTION_INV`) the `QTY_BASE` values associated with Transaction_Group(s) `'030', and '036'` (These are item depletions) and subtract quantities with `TRANSATION_GROUP = '020'`

So I should have for the `ON_QTY`calculation as of 9/4/18: 16 + (SUM OF -->(14+2+2+5+2+1+2+10-24+10+10-24) = **26**

So far I have wrote the below query to `SUM` the quantities (for the 030 and 036 (positive) quantities for transactions that occured between today (current date) and a hardcoded date (9/4/18 in this example), but I am struggling as to how I can add some type of `CASE WHEN` or conditional `IF` statement where if the `TRANSACTION_GROUP` is 030 or 036 then SUM the values together, and if the `TRANSACTION_GROUP` is 020 then SUBTRACT the values. The query currently does NOT get me the correct ON_HAND_QTY from 9/4/18 because of the lack of the conditional subtraction.

```
  SELECT A.INV_ITEM_ID, A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.QTY_ONHAND, A.DT_TIMESTAMP, 
  DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, B.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0) AS TRANSACTION_DT,
  (A.QTY_ONHAND + (SELECT SUM(BB.QTY_BASE) 
                  FROM PS_TRANSACTION_INV BB WHERE BB.TRANSACTION_DATE 
                  BETWEEN '2018-09-04' AND GETDATE() AND BB.INV_ITEM_ID  
                  = '1' 
                  AND BB.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'  
                  AND BB.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT AND BB.INV_ITEM_ID 
                  = B.INV_ITEM_ID)) AS QTY_ONHAND_AS_OF_DT

 FROM PS_BU_ITEMS_INV A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_TRANSACTION_INV B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT
  = A.BUSINESS_UNIT 
    AND B.INV_ITEM_ID = A.INV_ITEM_ID 
    AND DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, A.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0) = 
     DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, B.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
  WHERE B.INV_ITEM_ID = '1'
   AND B.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'
```

I'd like to have something to the effect of this:

```
SELECT 
A.INV_ITEM_ID, A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.QTY_ONHAND, A.DT_TIMESTAMP, 
  DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, B.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0) AS TRANSACTION_DT,
  (A.QTY_ONHAND + (CASE WHEN B.TRANSACTION_GROUP IN ('030', '036') THEN 
                             SUM(B.QTY_BASE)
                        WHEN B.TRANSACTION_GROUP = '020' THEN
                             SUM(-B.QTY_BASE) END AS ON_HANDS_AS_OF_DATE ) ) 
FROM PS_BU_ITEMS_INV A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_TRANSACTION_INV B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT
  = A.BUSINESS_UNIT 
    AND B.INV_ITEM_ID = A.INV_ITEM_ID 
    AND DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, A.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0) = 
     DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, B.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
  WHERE B.INV_ITEM_ID = '1'
   AND B.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'
   AND B.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-09-04' AND GETDATE()
```

This query does not work though. Any feedback is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here is my edited SQL, however it is returning the wrong conditionally calculated on-hands value. I even added in the additional criteria to the `CASE WHEN` for the date range and it still did not return the correct value (26).

```
SELECT 
A.INV_ITEM_ID, A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.QTY_ONHAND, A.DT_TIMESTAMP, 
  DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, B.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0) AS TRANSACTION_DT,
  (A.QTY_ONHAND + SUM(CASE WHEN B.TRANSACTION_GROUP IN ('030', '036') --AND B.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-09-04' AND GETDATE()  
                      THEN (B.QTY_BASE)
                        WHEN B.TRANSACTION_GROUP = '020' --AND B.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-09-04' AND GETDATE()  
                        THEN (-B.QTY_BASE) END   ) )
FROM PS_BU_ITEMS_INV A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_TRANSACTION_INV B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT
  = A.BUSINESS_UNIT 
    AND B.INV_ITEM_ID = A.INV_ITEM_ID 
    AND DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, A.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0) = 
     DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, B.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
  WHERE B.INV_ITEM_ID = '1'
   AND B.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'
   AND B.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-09-04' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY A.INV_ITEM_ID, A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.QTY_ONHAND, A.DT_TIMESTAMP, DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, B.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
```

**EDIT 2:**

I'm curious why this query gets my the correct quantity count (26) (I hardcoded the value from A.QTY_ONHAND for simplification)

```
SELECT  (32 + SUM(CASE WHEN B.TRANSACTION_GROUP IN ('030', '036') --AND B.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-09-04' AND GETDATE()  THEN 
                        THEN (B.QTY_BASE)
                        WHEN B.TRANSACTION_GROUP = '020' --AND B.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-09-04' AND GETDATE()  
                        THEN (-B.QTY_BASE) END   ) )
        FROM PS_TRANSACTION_INV B
        WHERE B.INV_ITEM_ID = '1'
   AND B.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'
   AND B.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-09-04' AND GETDATE()
```

And yet the query below (which uses the same conditional logic) gets me a different (incorrect) quantity?

```
SELECT 
A.INV_ITEM_ID, A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.QTY_ONHAND, A.DT_TIMESTAMP, 
  DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, B.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0) AS TRANSACTION_DT,
  (A.QTY_ONHAND + SUM(CASE WHEN B.TRANSACTION_GROUP IN ('030', '036') --AND B.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-09-04' AND GETDATE()  THEN 
                        THEN B.QTY_BASE
                        WHEN B.TRANSACTION_GROUP = '020' --AND B.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-09-04' AND GETDATE()  
                        THEN -B.QTY_BASE END   ) )
FROM PS_BU_ITEMS_INV A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_TRANSACTION_INV B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT
  = A.BUSINESS_UNIT 
    AND B.INV_ITEM_ID = A.INV_ITEM_ID 
    AND DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, A.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0) = 
        DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, B.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
  WHERE B.INV_ITEM_ID = '1'
   AND B.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'
   AND B.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2018-09-04' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY A.INV_ITEM_ID, A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.QTY_ONHAND, A.DT_TIMESTAMP, DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, B.DT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
```

Comment: Use conditional sum: `SUM(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <expr1> ELSE <expr2> END)`.

Comment: I think the issue of EDIT 2 is the grouping. You are including columns from table B when grouping and that may produce different subgroups.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL conditional addition or subtraction](//stackoverflow.com/q/1429769/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't debug your exact query. Nevertheless, below you can see how to conditionally sum values and subtract it to your current value so you can go back in time and find the original quantity:

Assuming your data is:

```
create table ps_bu_items_inv (
  business_unit varchar(20),
  inv_item_id int,
  qty_onhand decimal(12, 8),
  dt_timestamp datetime
);

insert into ps_bu_items_inv (business_unit, inv_item_id, qty_onhand, dt_timestamp)
  values ('11MMS', 1, 16.0, '2018-09-11 08:12:46.827');

create table ps_transaction_inv (
  business_unit varchar(20),
  inv_item_id int,
  transaction_date date,
  transaction_group varchar(6),
  qty_base decimal(12, 8),
  dt_timestamp datetime
);

insert into ps_transaction_inv (business_unit, inv_item_id, transaction_date, transaction_group, qty_base, dt_timestamp)
  values ('11MMS', 1, '2018-09-11', '036', 14, '2018-09-11 12:34:56');
insert into ps_transaction_inv (business_unit, inv_item_id, transaction_date, transaction_group, qty_base, dt_timestamp)
  values ('11MMS', 1, '2018-09-11', '020', 24, '2018-09-11 12:34:56');
insert into ps_transaction_inv (business_unit, inv_item_id, transaction_date, transaction_group, qty_base, dt_timestamp)
  values ('11MMS', 1, '2018-09-11', '030', 6, '2018-09-11 12:34:56');
```

The query should be similar to:

```
select a.*, b.*, (a.qty_onhand - b.change) as original_qty
  from ps_bu_items_inv a
  join (
    select
        inv_item_id,
        sum( -- here's the conditional sum
           case when transaction_group <> '020' then -qty_base else qty_base end
           ) as change
      from ps_transaction_inv
      where transaction_date between '2018-09-01' and '2018-09-11'
      group by inv_item_id
  ) b on a.inv_item_id = b.inv_item_id
```

Result:

```
business_unit  inv_item_id  qty_onhand  dt_timestamp  inv_item_id  change  original_qty
-------------  -----------  ----------  ------------  -----------  ------  ------------
11MMS          1            16          2018-09-11    1            4       12
```

As you see, the original quantity shows up as `12`. That is current one `16` minus the changes `4`. In this case, "changes" is computed as:

```
-14 +24 -6 = +4
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I edited the post above with my quest and it still does not pull in the correct calculated value. Any thoughts on if my query needs modification(s)?

Comment: The calculated field (CASE WHEN) appears to be ignoring the date criteria I have defined in the query for some reason...

Comment: Yes, it should ignore any conditon in the `WHERE` clause, and will sum all rows selected. However, it will sum them the way you want.

Comment: I edited the post again (EDIT 2 above) as I'm trying to understand why both queries produce different results ?